# Check whether a number can be dialed on a phone keypad without diagonal moves

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write/come up with an algorithm for a phone keypad traversal.

Let's say I have a rook on a keypad. The rook can traverse only horizontally and vertically. My code has to input a phone number and check whether the rook is able to dial it (shouldn't go diagonally) and return a boolean based on the result.

[image]

Example: A phone number "4632871" is termed as "true" since the rook can traverse without going diagonally whereas "4853267" is termed as "false"

Below is my code implementation:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

function rookTraversal(arr, phoneNumber) {

  var arrIndex = [],
    numArray = [];

  var number = phoneNumber.split('');

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      arrIndex.push([i, j]);
    }
  }

  arrIndex = arrIndex.map((item, index) => ({
    [index + 1]: item,
  }));

  number.forEach((item) => {
    numArray.push(arrIndex[item - 1]);
  });

  let numArrayKeys = numArray.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, Object.values(x).map((y) => y)], []);

  for (let i = 1; i < numArrayKeys.length; i++) {
    var x1 = numArrayKeys[i - 1][0][0];
    var y1 = numArrayKeys[i - 1][0][1];
    var x2 = numArrayKeys[i][0][0];
    var y2 = numArrayKeys[i][0][1];

    if (x1 !== x2 && y1 !== y2) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}


console.log(rookTraversal(data, '4631782'));
console.log(rookTraversal(data, '4853267'));
```

Is there a way to optimize this piece of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of different traits you could optimize for.  I like to optimize for lines of code, so I'll try that.

You can simplify the testing by building a "graph" (2-dimensional array) of reachable numbers.  Each row and column index is a phone digit.  If the value at (i,j) is true, then j is reachable from i.

To do this, take all the numbers in each digit's row/column and create an array where those indexes have a value of 1.

The reachability graph looks like this:

[image]

The digit 6 can reach 3,4,5,6,9 and you can see that `reachable[6][x]` is true for x=3,4,5,6 or 9.

Then simply run through the list of numbers and test if `reachable[current][next]` is true.

I've assumed the rook can dial repeated numbers like 3333.  If no, you can test for that in the graph creation or during reachability testing.

```js
function rookTraversal(rows, phoneNumber) { 
    var cols=rows[0].map((col, i) => rows.map(row => row[i])),
        digits=phoneNumber.match(/(\d)/g),
        reachable=[];
    for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < cols.length; col++) {
            reachable[ rows[row][col] ] = rows[row].concat(cols[col]).reduce( (map, value) => { map[value]=1; return map }, [] );
        }
    }
    // console.log({reachable,digits});
    for (var i=0; i<digits.length-1; ++i) if (! reachable[ digits[i] ][ digits[i+1] ]) return false;
    return true;
}

var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
];

console.log(rookTraversal(data, '4631782'));
console.log(rookTraversal(data, '4853267'));
```